# Is it possible to convert a font icon back into it's private use code?

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, character-encoding, html-entities

For example, I am using [fontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), and I have a span that contains an icon:

written in html:

```
<span class="icon">&#xf05a;</span>
```

though once actually rendered on the page:

```
<span class="icon"></span>
```

Is there any way to retrieve the special character code `f05a` once it has been rendered?

i.e.

```
var
code = $('.icon').html(),
privateUseCode;

console.log(code); // 

?????

privateUseCode = '\f05a'; // or similar
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: What do you need it for? I am asking cos it's kinda strange to want the code point in a hex string.

Comment: The part “once it has been rendered” in the question does not seem to make sense. Given the markup presented, the code point (character code) is there, in HTML source and in DOM, whether it gets displayed as something or not.

Comment: When I say "when it's rendered" I mean what you see in developer tools when you inspect it, as opposed to what's actually in the html file that I've written.

Comment: @Esailija So my use case is fairly niche: I have an alert system that inserts a template into my page, however if the same alert already exists (i.e. the icon, message and type are all the same), it makes it shake instead. To do this I keep track of all the alerts on the page.

However now some of the alerts are already on the page when it's rendered - so in order to calculate if two alerts are the same I need to find out what the original icon was in the same format that I insert them. Hence I need to know what the code was.

Comment: @Joshua and where in that scenario does a hex string come in ? :P It looks like you can do fine with the code point value as a number

Comment: @Esailija So I have a function something like makeAlert(location, message, icon){ ... }; and the icon is the private use code, so I might use it something like makeAlert('top', 'message sent', '&#xf0a5'). But if I want to check this particular combination of variables hasn't been used before on alerts that already existed on the page, I need to reverse engineer their value from the html. Message and location were easy but finding this hex code not wasn't! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Joshua Any reason you are not just doing something like http://jsfiddle.net/gaTR9/

Comment: @Esailija So that is pretty much what I am doing, however I am now also trying to accommodate for alerts that may have been pre-rendered in the page (rather than added by my makeAlert function) by searching for all elements with a certain class, then (to use your example) adding their msg, icon and location to combinationsSent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By using [toString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp) with a radix variable:**

```
var charCodeInBase16 = 61530.toString(16) // f05a
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dJQd/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var privateUseCode = $('.icon').text().charCodeAt(0);
```

Hopefully the html is as you represented, because whitespace screws this up

http://jsfiddle.net/hYpRF/

Comment: So this returns 61530 - but what I'm looking for is f05a, &#xf05a or similar. Can I turn 61530 into f05a somehow do you know?

Comment: @Joshua that only matters for superficial display. You can print a number in hex base by `privateUseCode.toString(16)`. What is stored in the variable is actual numeric value, which you can work with. The hex string can only be used for superficial display.